# R package link to C igraph

Tags: c, r, linker, igraph, r-package

I have some C codes that uses igraph C library. Now I want to make an R package from those.

My question is asked here before: [R package that links to external C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328156/r-package-that-links-to-external-c-library) 
But since it was asked 3 years ago, I wanted to make sure there is no update on it.

Is it possible that with using dependencies, I do not copy the whole igraph into my package? I am a bit familiar with makevars but I don't know how to find the correct path to igraph lib in each system.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about using R's [igraph package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/) instead?

Comment: I didnt get what you mean (or you didnt understand my question). I have some codes that are using igraph functions to work. So igraph package does not have my functions. I want to make my own package containing my own cpp files as well as igraph library.

Comment: I don't think there have been any improvements in the past three years. Unless igraph offers a C level API, you cannot call igraph C functions from another package.