# How to (easily) wrap a c++ function unto an easy to install R 'package'

Tags: c++, r, eigen

Suppose I have an c++ code (see below for a simple example). 
I want to make it easy for a journal referee to install/run 
it.

So i figured the easiest way is to warp it unto a simplified 
R package-like tar.gz file so the referee could install it 
by simply invoking install.packages to a local .tar.gz file.

The reason for this is that i do not know what machine the
 referee is using, but i'm pretty sure the referee would 
know how to install a R packages so it's much easier for 
me to warp my code as a R 'package' --or at any rate, 
something sufficiently similar to it that it could be 
installed by a simple call to install.package().

An answer to a earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5172509/189035) seems to suggest this 
is indeed possible. I followed the suggestions therein and 
created a /src directory with my cpp code (the one shown 
below) and a Makevars.win file containing:

```
## This assume that we can call Rscript to ask Rcpp about its locations
## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
#PKG_LIBS = $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript.exe -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()")
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include -I.
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -DEIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript.exe -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()") $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

and a Makevars file containing:

```
## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
#PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` 
# This was created by RcppEigen.package.skeleton, but the R script that is 
# called creates error message:
# PKG_CPPFLAGS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "RcppEigen:::RcppEigenCxxFlags()"`
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -DEIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

e.g. I simply followed the answer in the SO post to look around for how 
this is done in other packages (I also add RcppEigen to the list of dependencies because 
this guarantees that Eigen is installed on the target machine). I also created a /R directory containing the file MSE.R which contains:

```
fx01<-function(x){
    x<-as.matrix(x)
    Dp<-rep(0,ncol(x))
    fit<-.C("mse",as.integer(nrow(x)),as.integer(ncol(x)),as.single(x),as.single(Dp))
    as.numeric(fit[[4]])
}
```

and an empty /inst/include  and a /man directory containing a minimal (but valid) .Rd file. 
I've added a NAMESPACE file containing:

```
import(Rcpp)
import(RcppEigen)
useDynLib(MySmallExample)
```

Here is the question:

- the c++ function otherwise compiles/runs fine. Is there a way to warp it unto a R package so as to make it easy to install/run by a third person.

Here is the c++ code used for this example.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <Eigen/SVD>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using Eigen::MatrixXf;
using Eigen::VectorXf;


float median(VectorXf& x) {
    int n=x.rows();
    int half=(n+1)/2;   
    half--;                 
    float med;
    nth_element(x.data(),x.data()+half,x.data()+x.size());  
    if((n%2)==1){
        med=x(half);
    } else {
        float tmp0=x(half);
        float tmp1=x.segment(half+1,half-1).minCoeff(); 
        med=0.5*(tmp0+tmp1);
    }
    return med;
}
VectorXf fx01(MatrixXf& x){
    int p=x.cols();
    int n=x.rows();
    VectorXf Recept(n);
    VectorXf Result(p);
    for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
        Recept=x.col(i);
        Result(i)=median(Recept);
    }
    return Result;
}
extern "C"{
    void mse(int* n,int* p,float* x,float* medsout){
        MatrixXf x_cen=Map<MatrixXf>(x,*n,*p);  
        VectorXf MedsOut=fx01(x_cen);
        Map<VectorXf>(medsout,*p)=MedsOut.array();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very important to have a proper DESCRIPTION file. 
I used this one:

```
Package: MySmallExample
Type: Package
Title: MysmallExample
Version: 0.0.0
Date: 2012-12-24
Depends: Rcpp (>= 0.9.10)
Imports: RcppEigen (>= 0.2.0)
Suggests: mvtnorm
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppEigen
Description: A small minimal Package.
License: GPL (>= 2)
LazyLoad: yes
Authors@R: person("joe", "programer", email =
        "joe.programer@joe_inc.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Collate: 'MSE.R'
Packaged: 2012-12-24 12:34:56 UTC; andi
Author: joe programer [aut, cre]
Maintainer: joe programer <joe.programer@joe_inc.com>
Repository: CRAN
Date/Publication: 2012-12-24 12:34:56
```

The most important thing seems to be the 'Collate:' field: it should properly list 
all the .R files in the /R directory. The Depends & Imports field should also be consistent with the NAMESPACE file.

It is also very important that the file NAMESPACE contains a line

```
export("fx01","fx02")
```

where "fx01","fx02" are the name of all the R functions in the 
/R/*.R files (in this case, just fx01).

Then, I wrapped the whole thing unto a .tar.gz. and ran

```
install.packages("MySmallExample.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")


> install.packages("/MySmallExample.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
Installing package(s) into ‘/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘MySmallExample’ ...
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include  -I"/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/Rcpp/include" -I"/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RcppEigen/include"  -DEIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE -fopenmp -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c MSE.cpp -o MSE.o
g++ -shared -o MySmallExample.so MSE.o -L/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/Rcpp/lib -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/Rcpp/lib -fopenmp -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/MySmallExample/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (MySmallExample)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the `Writing R Extensions' manual about how to interface with R?

You are *of course* free to do this without Rcpp, but we wrote Rcpp for our use as we find that it makes these very interchanges easier. 94 packages on CRAN which use Rcpp appear to agree...

You are using Eigen, and you want this packaged for a third party ("a referee"). Now, if you were to use RcppEigen *you would assured that Eigen is present as it is inside RcppEigen*.  With what you do, you're not...

Plus, `.C()` is a much more restrictive interface that `.Call()`.

Comment: No, I haven't read that document. I was hoping somebody could point me to a shorter version (i'm not looking to submit to cran any-time soon --just to use R's infrastructure as a carrier). Thanks, your third paragraph is strong argument to call RcppEigen --i've edited the question accordingly. I agree on the merits of .Call() vs .C() but at this point my code is already written without R in mind. I'm just looking for a hassle-free way to make it easy to run/install by somebody not necessarily computer proficient (beyond tipping 'install.package' in R)